# Cleaning the json data

Tags: python-3.x

The data is stored in the Pandas data frame. One of the columns has data in JSON format. How can I get the new column for the different fields like start, last, type? 
Secondly, the metadata column has stored 2 ids i.e. id 72; id 73 for the same order_id. I want to split the ids into different rows.

Order_id - 10001

```
Metadata-
    ["java.util.ArrayList", [{"id": 72, "name": "ABC", "rank": null, "type": "web", "kind": "type_A", "start": 1897, "last": 1, "variable": "$$", "describe": "Category$$", "requesteddate": [2000, 7, 1], "initialization_id": 1031, "id_1": ["java.util.ArrayList", []], "Code": 13000, "retailFxRate": {"base": "$$", "rate": ["java.math.decimal", 1.2], "request": [2000, 7, 1], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "common": 526, "meaning": "Category$$", "Code1": {"base": "$$", "rate": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 1], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "retailvariable": "$$", "id1": -1}, {"id": 73, "name": "DEF", "rank": null, "type": "web", "kind": "type_A", "start": 1679, "category": null, "variable": "hjk", "describe": "Category$$", "requesteddate": [2000, 6, 30], "initialization_id": 1031, "ExtraIds": ["java.util.ArrayList", []], "PNR": 1344900, "retailFxRate": {"base": "HUF", "rate": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 0.004795], "request": [2000, 6, 30], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "common": 6449, "meaning": "Category$$", "Code1": {"base": "$$", "rate": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 1], "request": [2000, 8, 10], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "retailvariable": "$$", "CodeConverted": 6449, "common": 6449}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a dataframe that corresponds to your example

```
import pandas as pd
DFR = pd.DataFrame(columns=["order_id","json_data"])
DFR.at[0] = [10001,["java.util.ArrayList", [{"id": 72, "name": "ABC", "rank": None, "type": "web", "kind": "type_A", "start": 1897, "last": 1, "variable": "$$", "describe": "Category$$", "requesteddate": [2000, 7, 1], "initialization_id": 1031, "id_1": ["java.util.ArrayList", []], "Code": 13000, "retailFxRate": {"base": "$$", "rate": ["java.math.decimal", 1.2], "request": [2000, 7, 1], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "common": 526, "meaning": "Category$$", "Code1": {"base": "$$", "rate": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 1], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "retailvariable": "$$", "id1": -1}, {"id": 73, "name": "DEF", "rank": None, "type": "web", "kind": "type_A", "start": 1679, "category": None, "variable": "hjk", "describe": "Category$$", "requesteddate": [2000, 6, 30], "initialization_id": 1031, "ExtraIds": ["java.util.ArrayList", []], "PNR": 1344900, "retailFxRate": {"base": "HUF", "rate": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 0.004795], "request": [2000, 6, 30], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "common": 6449, "meaning": "Category$$", "Code1": {"base": "$$", "rate": ["java.math.BigDecimal", 1], "request": [2000, 8, 10], "sign": "$$", "type": "webpage"}, "retailvariable": "$$", "CodeConverted": 6449, "common": 6449}]]]
print(DFR)

  order_id                                          json_data
0    10001  [java.util.ArrayList, [{'id': 72, 'name': 'ABC...
```

Clean what is inside the column to focus only on the json files

```
DFR["json_data"] = DFR["json_data"].apply(lambda x: (x[1][0],x[1][1]))
print(DFR)

  order_id                                          json_data
0    10001  ({'id': 72, 'name': 'ABC', 'rank': None, 'type...
```

Split tuple of jsons into two rows for one unique order_id

Lastly, extract json content to other columns

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(DFR.json_data.values.tolist(), index=DFR.order_id)
final_df = final_df.stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name='json_data')
final_df["start"] = final_df["json_data"].apply(lambda x: x["start"])
print(final_df)

   order_id                                          json_data  start
0     10001  {'id': 72, 'name': 'ABC', 'rank': None, 'type'...   1897
1     10001  {'id': 73, 'name': 'DEF', 'rank': None, 'type'...   1679
```